# Webpack/React json file not loading externally on build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Im trying to use the azure environment variables with my react build. So far I have an appsettings.json file that I load into react with:

```
import settings from './appsettings.json';
```

I then have webpack copy the json into build folder which goes to azure. However I think after build the app isnt actually loading the file as I can see some of my variables embedded in the "chunk.js" so its not actually reaching out the the json file in root anymore? Am I importing the file in the wrong way?

C

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

- var json = require('./data.json'); //with path
- change your `settings.json` to `settings.js` and use `module.exports = {}` in it.

I believe azure would accept different forms of setting files, not limited to `json`.